# Trying to us ComputeManagementClient

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to get VM information from Azure VM's by using ComputeManagementClient but when i invoke this:

```
var computeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credential) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId };

var vmResult = await computeManagementClient.VirtualMachines.GetAsync(groupName, vmName, InstanceViewTypes.InstanceView);
```

I get this:

> {"Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."}
>
> Inner exception {"Cannot get SerializationBinder because an
>   ISerializationBinder was previously set."}

The error occurs on the second line.

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/2552) might be related, the workaround was downgrading Newtonsoft.Json to 9.0.1

Comment: Downgrading Newtonsoft.json to version 9.01 did the job. Just remove version 9.0.2 forcefully and run this command in the Package Manager Console: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is related to [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/2552), actually [this comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/2552#issuecomment-261813909) is directly related to VM.

The workaround is downgrading Newtonsoft.Json to 9.0.1, which can be done by  forcefully removing version 9.0.2 and running this command in the Package Manager Console: `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1` (as Eric Feurich stated).